# Установка pip из архива Windows

Tags: python, pip

Я хочу упаковать питон и все зависимости моего кода в один дистрибутив. Скачал [архив](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.5/python-3.6.5-embed-amd64.zip) с питоном, прописал путь к нему в моих скриптах, работает. Не могу разобраться, как установить другие модули. Если скачивать их и пытаться запустить, получаю ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./packages/setuptools-51.1/setuptools-51.1.0/setup.py", line 7, in <module>
    import setuptools
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'
```

Скрипт, который я запускаю:

```
#! ./python-3.6.5-embed-amd64/python.exe
from subprocess import call
call(["python", "./packages/setuptools-51.1/setuptools-51.1.0/setup.py"])
```

Но чтобы поставить тот же `setuptools` нужен `setuptools`.

Как еще можно установить `pip` или `setuptools` из локальной директории?

Comment: Создайте cmd файл, из которого вызывайте `pip install path\to\package` для нужных пакетов.

Comment: @Lecron cmd(bat) не поможет вызвать то чего нет, а pip по умолчанию отсутствует.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как понимаю вы используете embedded архив.
Для установки pip в python37._pth (вместо 37 Ваша версия) раскомментируйте строку

```
import site
```

Далее скачиваем установщик pip: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py и закидываем в папку к python.exe.

Переходим в папку с embedded Python и устанавливаем pip:

```
python.exe get-pip.py
```

Проверяем работоспособность

```
Scripts\pip.exe -V
```

Путь к pip в данном случае относительно python.exe. Вообще всегда надо будет прописывать путь к pip.exe.

Comment: Помогло. Спасибо большое!